# How can sort records by low value. All record in same row in my table

Tags: php, mysql

How can i sort the records with same values:

This is the example of values currently i have in my table

```
record_id a_id b_id c_id a_value b_value c_value
       25 A    B    C    450     390     395
```

Sorry im not able to create table here.

I'm using Php/MySQL Backend.

I need the following output:

```
B 390
C 395
A 450
```

It should be sort by lower value with the id name as well.

I know if all these records in different different rows. it was easy to sort by small value. buy using MIN function of mysql.

Im not sure how to sort this in same row records.

Comment: I forget to mention. In this same values are A,B,C

Comment: You need to sort values in the same row in ascending order?

Comment: you can't, since those values are all in  single record. a single query cannot produce multiple rows from one record, unless you do things like `union all` queries.

Comment: "I know if all these records in different different rows. it was easy" Well, there's your answer then

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with php, for example:

```
<?php
$row = ...

$myArray = array(
    'A' => $row['a_value'],
    'B' => $row['b_value'],
    'C' => $row['c_value'],
);

asort($myArray);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

If you like to make it dynamic then you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$row = ...

$myArray = array();
foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
    if (strpos($column, '_value') !== FALSE) {
        $myArray[strtoupper(substr($column, 1))] = $value;
    }
}

asort($myArray);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT record_id, mim(
    SELECT a_value FROM table t2 WHERE t1.record_id = t1.record_id UNION ALL
    SELECT b_value FROM table t3 WHERE t3.record_id = t1.record_id UNION ALL
    SELECT c_value FROM table t4 WHERE t4.record_id = t1.record_id )
FROM table t1
```

Your sql should fallow the logic above. I can´t test as i dont have mysql in this pc.